# Using jQuery to change image source dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that is a series of N img elements. I need each image to, when clicked, change to the next image in their own series of three. I have listed my html below to explain.

```
<body>
    <div class="images">
        <div class="image_group">
            <img id="first" src="group1_image1"></img>
            <img id="second" src="group1_image2"></img> //this isn't displayed until clicked
            <img id="third" src="group1_image3"></img> //when this is displayed, it cycles back to group1image1
         </div>
         ...
         <div class="image_group">
            <img id="first" src="groupN_image1"></img>
            <img id="second" src="groupN_image2"></img>
            <img id="third" src="groupN_image3"></img>
          </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Each image_group div displays only one image until clicked, when it displays the second, then the third when clicked, then cycles back to the first when clicked a third time.

My problem is writing a JQuery method that can do this cycling by making "second" images replace "first" images when clicked and so on. The below method rewrites the image source which seems silly but I can't think of a better way to do it. I'm also not sure if the "first" class image will be isolated in the "image_group" div (as it should) or if it will change all images on the page to their "second" class image.

```
$("#first").attr("src","group1_image2.jpg");
```

Can anyone think of a way to do this?

Comment: Remember that IDs **must be unique** in your document.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
$("image_group img").on("click", function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $(this).attr("src", index === $("img").length - 1 ? $(this).next().src : $("img")[0].src); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

refine your html:

```
<body>
    <div class="images">
        <div class="image_group">
            <img id="1,1" data_num="1,1" src="group1_image1"></img>
         </div>
         ...
         <div class="image_group">
            <img id="n,1" data_num="n,1" src="groupN_image1"></img>
          </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

and then you might do something like:

```
$("image_group img").on("click", function() {
    var max = 3;
    var indexes = $(this).data('num').split(',');
    if ( indexes[1] == max
       indexes[1] = 1;
    else 
       indexes[1]++;
    $(this).attr("src", "group" + indexes[0] + "_image" + indexes[1]); 
    $(this).data('num', indexes.join(','))
});
```